# O que é e como funciona o blockchain?

Tags: segurança, blockchain

O que é blockchain e como ele funciona?

Em que contextos, fora criptomoedas, ele pode ser implementado e por que seria viável a implementação dele nesses contextos?

Comment: Um exemplo de Critpomoeda: [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.org/en/).

Comment: tinha colocado na resposta mas o pessoal deletou, esse vídeo é muito bom para entender o que é blockchain https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_160oMzblY8

Comment: [Explicando blockchain para crianças de cinco anos](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/explicando-o-blockchain-para-crianças-de-cinco-anos-eli5-americano)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> O que é blockchain e como ele funciona?

O conceito básico de **blockchain** é bastante simples: um banco de dados distribuído que mantém uma lista de registros ordenados em uma sequência crescente.

Este conceito foi originalmente publicado por [Satoshi Nakamoto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satoshi_Nakamoto) no artigo "Bitcoin: A Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System" [(link para versão PDF)](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) em 2008 e o qual serviu de base para o fonte do [Bitcoin](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin) lançado em 2009.

Em si o conceito visa agrupar os registros (diga-se: blocos) formando assim a própria "cadeia de blocos" (blockchain) distribuindo-a de maneira descentralizada através de uma rede [Peer-to-peer](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) aonde o consenso dos "pares" conectados são responsáveis pela aceitação (ou não) de um novo bloco adicionado a **blockchain**.

De maneira **básica** para montar a extrutura de um bloco são necessários: índice, timestamp, dados, hash e hash do bloco anterior.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que o **hash** do bloco anterior deve ser encontrado no bloco que se pretende adicionar afim de preservar a integridade da cadeia.

O primeiro bloco chamado de **"bloco de gênese"** deve ser codificado na matriz (normalmente o servidor que coordena a rede [Peer-to-peer](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer)).

Pela integridade do **blockchain** deve haver sempre apenas um conjunto explícito de blocos na cadeia e no caso de conflitos (caso dois pares da rede gerem o mesmo número de bloco) deve-se escolher a cadeia com o maior número de blocos rejeitando assim a adição de bloco vindo do "par" que tem o menor número de blocos.

A característica principal do **blockchain** (o conceito) é compartilhar e sincronizar a cadeia de blocos com os pares na rede e para isto é necessário criar regras para este fluxo como por exemplo:

- Quando um par gera um novo bloco, ele o transmite para a rede
- Quando um par se conecta a um novo número, ele consulta o último bloco
- Quando um par encontra um bloco com um índice maior do que o atual bloco conhecido, ele adiciona o bloco a sua corrente atual ou as consultas para a cadeia de blocos completa(sincronizando)

Não acredito que caiba aqui (uma simples dissertação sobre o conceito) abordar temas como mineração ou prova de trabalho visto que isto é especifico de transações (para uso de validação em [criptomoedas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptomoeda), contratos inteligentes, etc...), desde a publicação deste conceito até hoje, outros conceitos correlacionados surgiram: as [altchains](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altchains) que têm por objetivo serem alternativas ao [Bitcoin](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin) e portanto gerenciam sua própria rede e seu próprio **blockchain** e os [sidechain](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidechain) que surgiram com o objetivo de validar outros **blockchains**.

Diga-se vale citar um trecho da definição de [sidechain](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidechain) descrito pela [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org):

> [Sidechain](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidechain) é uma **blockchain** que valida dados de outras **blockchains**. Essa tecnologia foi desenvolvida como uma alternativa para promover integração entre **blockchains** e adicionar funcionalidades, sem a necessidade de se modificar os scripts das **blockchains**. Desde a introdução do [Bitcoin](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin) por [Satoshi Nakamoto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satoshi_Nakamoto) em 2008, diversas cadeias de blocos alternativas, denominadas [altchains](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altchains), foram criadas, cada uma dessas com sua própria tecnologia e sua própria [criptomoeda](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptomoeda), as [Altcoins](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altcoins). A existência de diversas **blockchains** isoladas gerou uma fragmentação dos mercados e do desenvolvimento. [Sidechains](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidechain) surgiram como uma alternativa para solucionar esses problemas, permitindo que ativos possam ser movidos entre as cadeias.

Embora seja difícil pensar em um (o conceito) sem o outro ([criptomoedas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptomoeda)) pela sua própria origem, o **blockchain** por ser um conceito livre de marcas ou patentes não esta explicitamente atrelado ao uso de [criptomoedas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptomoeda), plataformas de pagamentos ou contratos inteligentes e possui uma gama considerável de aplicações possíveis e até mesmo que ainda não foram pensadas ou mesmo implementadas.

---

> Em que contextos, fora criptomoedas, ele pode ser implementado?

O **blockchain** não é uma tecnologia e nem um protocolo (ainda) ele é o que é: um conceito.

Como um conceito ele pode ser implementado da melhor maneira a qual seu desenvolvedor, grupo, ou organização acreditar que lhe provem, como surgiu para servir de base a um modelo de moeda digital descentralizada (o que por si só já é uma ruptura dos métodos tradicionais de transações monetárias) a grande gama de aplicações decorrentes seguiu este nicho, até então novo e com um grande espaço para ser disputado (e monetizado).

Contudo este conceito pode ser aplicado a uma grande gama de aplicações que não necessariamente estejam relacionadas a criptomoedas e contratos inteligentes uma vez que os dados (blocos) são distribuídos e auditados pela própria rede provendo assim sua integridade livre de interferência de um mediador central ao qual se deposite confiança podem surgir possibilidades de uso tais como em:

- Governança:

  - distribuir dados de gastos públicos de maneira mais transparente e auditável
  - prover um mecanismo de identificação de cidadãos nacional (ou global)
  - um sistema de informações clinicas globais (área de saúde)
  - auditar de maneira publica e transparente o sistema eletrônico de votação
  - inovar o campo dos registros públicos e do sistema notarial
  - inovar a área de registros de imóveis
  - mapear informações de censo demográfico de maneira mais eficiente

A área de **governança** (diga-se administração pública) é realmente muito ampla, tudo praticamente envolve informações (dados) desde o simples censo demográfico até a arrecadação de impostos. No caso de registros e tabelionatos estes agentes intermediários servem como um ponto de confiança que nesta "disruptiva" nova realidade apresentada pelo uso de **blockchains** seriam obsoletos.

- Patentes, Copyright e Royalties

  - um sistema unificado para registros

Basicamente hoje, patentear, definir direitos e seus royalties são processos fragmentados e variam de país a país sob a definição de suas diferentes leis. Todas as disputas envolvendo estas questões culminam em longos processos que dependem do sistema de leis locais (do local de disputa), um sistema unificado seria menos suscetível a fraudes, poderia reger regras globais, diminuir os custos e tornar mais transparente as ação dos intermediários além de encurtar o tempo de disputas.

- Administração

  - distribuir dados publico de maneira mais eficiente
  - prover interoperabilidade entre os dados de **blockchains** (sidechains)

Referente a área de **administração** pública ou privada é inevitável pensar em dados e informações sem imaginar uma enorme pilha de papéis e fichários de pequena estantes a grandes galpões. Desde que entramos na era da informática isto tem diminuído más esta longe do fim graças a imposição do sistema burocrático, o uso de **blockchains** nesta área reduziria consideravelmente o uso de papéis e os custos envolvidos.

- Aplicações (desktop, mobile, IoT, ...)

  - distribuir ou recuperar dados descentralizados
  - criar novos paradigmas de segurança distribuída

Embora os exemplos acima possam parecer poucos podem derivar centenas ou milhares de casos de uso para **aplicações**.

Os casos de uso não se estendem unica e exclusivamente a uso de dados **públicos** note-se também o possível caso de dados **privados** isso é claro depende da proposta de uso do sistema em questão e como este sistema deverá prover o acesso e a distribuição de dados.

---

#### Dificuldades:

Talvez o maior dos paradigmas que impeçam a expansão do uso de sistemas baseados neste conceito das **blockchains** se deva ao fato da fragmentação em diversas **blockchains**.

Outro ponto se refere a falta de legislação a respeito de como e onde poderia ser usados o conceito de blocos. Por exemplo:

Se a administração pública utiliza-se um registro de cidadãos baseados em **blockchain** empresas, sites, governos, sistemas e aplicações no geral poderiam usar estas informações no caso de uso de aferir que um usuário é único e que suas informações são "fidedignas".

Isso abriria um leque para iniciativas privadas ou colaborativas para praticamente tudo o que hoje já existe mas é fragmentados entre serviços e seus provedores.

Muitas questões se abrem aqui também tais como: quem seria responsável por definir regras, o nível de sensibilidade dos dados e os direitos e deveres de poder usá-los e manipulá-los.

Isso tudo passa pela necessidade de definir legislações e possíveis tratados internacionais e com certeza os primeiros trabalhos mais relevantes serão visto nas próximas décadas pelas nações que possuem um sistema legislativo mais eficiente e avançado.

---

#### Exemplos:

A lista a seguir mostra casos de uso de **blockchain** (alguns para criptomoedas e pagamentos) por startups:

- Peer-to-perr pagamentos e empréstimos:

  - [Abra](https://www.goabra.com/)
  - [BTC Jam](https://btcjam.com/)
  - [Bitbond](https://www.bitbond.com/)
  - [Circle](https://www.circle.com/)
  - [Plutus](https://plutus.it/how-it-works)
- Internet das Coisas (IoT):

  - [Chimera-inc](http://www.chimera-inc.io/)
  - [Filament](http://filament.com/)
- Sistema de votos:

  - [Follow my Vote](https://followmyvote.com/)
- Cambio e remessa:

  - [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/?locale=en)
  - [Ripple](https://ripple.com/)
  - [BitPesa](https://www.bitpesa.co/)
  - [Chain.com](http://chain.com/)
  - [Stellar](https://www.stellar.org/about/mandate/)
- Transporte Colaborativo:

  - [La'Zooz](http://www.lazooz.net/)
  - [Arcade City](http://arcade.city/)
- Mercados descentralizados:

  - [Open Bazaar](https://openbazaar.org/)
  - [Slock.it](https://slock.it/)
- Prova de autoria e propriedade:

  - [Proofofexistence](https://proofofexistence.com/)
  - [Blocktech](http://blocktech.com/)
  - [Clipperz](https://clipperz.is/)
  - [Stampery](https://stampery.com/)
  - [Bitproof](https://bitproof.io/)
  - [Blockai](https://blockai.com/)
- Distribuição de energia:

  - [LO3](http://lo3energy.com/)
  - [Brooklyn Microgrid](http://brooklynmicrogrid.com/)
  - [Solar Change](http://www.solarchange.co/)
- Endossos e prova de identidade:

  - [ShoCard](https://shocard.com/)
  - [UniquID](http://uniquid.co/)
  - [Traity](https://www.traity.org/decentralized-identity-and-reputation)
  - [Onename](https://onename.com/)
  - [The World Table](https://www.worldtable.co/)
- armazenamento de dados:

  - [Tierion](https://tierion.com/)
  - [Peernova](http://peernova.com/)
  - [NXT](https://nxt.org/)
  - [Filecoin](http://filecoin.io/)
- Serviços de custódia:

  - [IBT](http://ibt.tech/)
- Contratos inteligentes:

  - [Mirror](https://mirror.co/)
  - [UbiMS](http://www.ubims.com/)
  - [Blockstream](https://blockstream.com/)
  - [Hedgy](http://www.hedgy.co/)
- Plataformas de previsão e jogos online:

  - [SatoshiDice](http://www.satoshidice.com/)
  - [Augur](https://www.augur.net/)
  - [Deckbound](https://www.deckbound.com/)
- Digitalização de documentos e contratos:

  - [Colu](https://www.colu.co/)
- Comércio de segurança digital:

  - [Symbiont](http://symbiont.io/)
  - [Security Asset Exchange](http://www.secureae.com/)
  - [Bitshares](https://bitshares.org/)
- Autenticação de produtos de luxo e médico:

  - [Everledger](http://www.everledger.io/)
  - [ChainLink](https://www.linkedin.com/company/chainlink)
  - [Blockverify](http://www.blockverify.io/)
  - [Provenance](https://www.provenance.org/)
- Serviços governamentais:

  - [Bitnation](https://bitnation.co/)
  - [Stampery](https://stampery.com/)
  - [Shocard](https://shocard.com/)

Os créditos desta lista: [17 Blockchain Disruptive Use Cases](https://everisnext.com/2016/05/31/blockchain-disruptive-use-cases/)

---

#### Referencias e estudo:

- Um exemplo prático do conceito de **blockchain**

  - post: ["A blockchain in 200 lines of code"](https://medium.com/@lhartikk/a-blockchain-in-200-lines-of-code-963cc1cc0e54)
  - [código fonte escrito em javascript (nodejs)](https://github.com/lhartikk/naivechain)
- IBM Watson IoT Examples

  - [Samples demonstrating](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/blockchain-samples)
  - [Introduction to Hyperledger Smart Contracts for IoT](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/blockchain-samples/blob/master/docs/HyperledgerContractsIntroBestPracticesPatterns.md)
- Posts

  - [Como usar a Blockchain para promover o interesse público?](https://feed.itsrio.org/como-usar-a-blockchain-para-promover-o-interesse-p%C3%BAblico-c7fb1f7e186e)
  - [21 Blockchain Examples and Applications](http://indiantechnologyblog.com/blockchain-examples/)
  - [17 Blockchain Applications That Are Transforming Society](https://blockgeeks.com/guides/blockchain-applications/)
- [A very simple BlockChain implementation in PHP](https://github.com/rhondle/BlockChain)
- [Lista de pesquisa de repositórios no GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=blockchain&type=)

---

Os exemplos e referencias aqui levantados são significativamente pequenos em números pois existem muitos mais e muitos com maior ou menor relevância ou publicidade podem ter ficado de fora desta listagem.

De maneira lógica e de um ponto de vista **"pessoal"** acredito que o futuro das aplicações que utilizam o conceito de **blockchain** deva mesmo ser a fragmentação o que vai elevar consideravelmente uso de **sidechains**. Além do que nossa sociedade não esta preparada (nem sequer começou a discutir) a disruptura para com os métodos tradicionais de manuseio de dados.

Answer (score 5):

**Blockchain**, como o nome em inglês diz, é uma cadeia de blocos. Ela serve como um banco de dados distribuído cuja validade pode ser verificada por qualquer um, de modo que a segurança e transparência do sistema são garantidos.

Tudo começa com um conceito de *transação*, que é uma operação atômica, que precisa ser entrada no registro de transações. Pode ser uma transferência de dinheiro como em [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.org/) ou [Bitshares](https://bitshares.org/), pode ser um contrato automatizado como em [Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/), pode ser um voto como em [Follow my vote](https://followmyvote.com/), pode ser alguma outra coisa que ainda não vi como Blockchain ou que ainda ninguém pensou. Mas o que essas transações todas têm em comum é que elas precisam:

1. Estar registradas na base de dados, de modo que qualquer um possa inspecionar a *blockchain* e vê-las lá;
2. A criação de novos blocos na cadeia tem que ser suficientemente complexa para que os blocos sejam criados a uma velocidade média predeterminada, mas a verificação da validade dos blocos já criados tem que ser extremamente simples e rápida, para que todos possam percorrer o histórico das transações com facilidade;
3. O histórico de transações não pode ser fraudável.

A *blockchain* faz uso de algoritmos que permitam que essas propriedade sejam satisfeitas.

Uma *blockchain* começa a vida como uma coleção de transações *pendentes*, isto é, que não estão em nenhum bloco. Essas transações são replicadas pela rede, e alguns usuários podem tentar coletar algumas delas e criar um *bloco* a partir das mesmas, um processo conhecido como *mineração*. Na mineração, toma-se a referência ao bloco anterior e às transações pendentes com as quais se quer criar o bloco e se resolve um problema de criptografia cuja dificuldade é ajustável pela rede. Uma vez resolvido, o bloco está criado e é replicado através da rede; os mineradores vão então passar a usar este novo bloco para criar os blocos subsequentes.

Se, é claro, mais de um minerador conseguir gerar um bloco antes de perceber que os outros conseguiram, estes vão competir para ver qual cadeia vai prevalecer: aquela que conseguir adicionar mais um bloco passa a ser a válida, uma vez que os clientes preferem sempre a cadeia mais longa, ou a primeira que receberam se virem uma outra com o mesmo comprimento. Eventualmente uma vai emergir como o consenso.

Answer (score 0):

O Blockchain foi introduzido como a tecnologia subjacente que impulsionou o Bitcoin - a primeira criptomoeda. Pense nisso como a infra-estrutura para a criptomoeda - se as criptomoedas fossem carros, blockchain seriam as estradas. Embora haja algum debate entre os especialistas sobre o futuro das criptomoedas, não há debate sobre o futuro brilhante da tecnologia blockchain.

Um blockchain é basicamente uma cadeia de blocos. Os blocos contêm informações digitais - imagine-os como pacotes de dados todos amarrados, como um presente de Natal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso do blockchain do Bitcoin:

Dentro de cada bloco há uma série de transações de Bitcoin que ocorreram dentro de um determinado período de tempo.
Todos os blocos juntos constituem o blockchain do Bitcoin e testemunham todas as transações que ocorreram desde a sua criação.

Cada bloco dentro de um blockchain contém alguns dados. No caso do Bitcoin, os dados são uma série de transações. Esses dados são organizados em uma única pasta digital. Esta pasta - o bloco neste caso - é confirmada por um mineiro, que adiciona ao bloco anterior no blockchain.

Novos blocos de transações são gravados no blockchain do Bitcoin a cada poucos minutos. Isso é chamado de blocos de "mineração". Essa ação vincula os novos blocos à cadeia de blocos já existente.

Mas, para ser adicionado à cadeia de blocos existente, novos blocos precisam ser validados. Esse é o papel dos nós. No caso do Bitcoin, os nós são responsáveis ​​por validar as transações do Bitcoin que ocorrem na rede do Bitcoin. A maneira como isso funciona é que os mineiros escolhem quais transações incluir em um novo bloco. Em seguida, os nós verificam todas as transações no bloco. Por fim, se tudo estiver bem, os nós retransmitem o novo bloco para outros nós.

Se você quiser ler um [guia completo](https://cryptomaniaks.com/guides/blockchain-for-dummies-ultimate-blockchain-101-guide) sobre blockchain, acho que este é um bom recurso.